# How to get a token without interacting with web pages

Tags: docusignapi

In sandbox environment, I can use the generator to generate token and try to api, but for production, how do i achive this.
I might run a background job to fetch the data, so won't be able to interact with page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "background" apps that are running without user interaction, you'll want to use the JWT grant workflow. JWT requires you to grant consent once, then the application can freely generate tokens with no further interaction required.

More information is available in the Developer Center: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken